# Jquery: Loop through all label element inside a div and comapre label to check the checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
    <div id="update-checkbox" class="row update-checkbox" data-company-code="10000005980" data-type="Contractual Customer,Shipper">
        <input type="checkbox" value="2" data-original-title="">
            <div class="span3">
                <label class="checkbox">Contractual Customer<input type="checkbox" value="2" data-original-title=""></label>
            </div>
            <div class="span3">
                <label class="checkbox">Shipper<input type="checkbox" value="3" data-original-title=""></label>
            </div>
        </div>


    var partyTypes = $("#update-checkbox").attr("data-type"); // gives  "Contractual Customer,Shipper
     $.each(partyTypes.split(','),
         function(i, opt) {
            //here i need to loop through all the label and checkbox inside div (id = update-checkbox) and  if the party type equals to the label then check that check box 

         });
```

for ex, if partytype = Contractual Customer, then select the check the corresponding checkbox

Comment: I don't see any attribute `data-party-type`

Comment: that should be `data-type`. i think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think instead of looping through the array, you can iterate the labels and see whether it is there in the array like

```
var partyTypes = $("#update-checkbox").attr("data-type")||''; 
partyTypes = partyTypes.replace(/,\s+/g, ',');
var array = partyTypes.split(',');
$('#update-checkbox label.checkbox').filter(function () {
    return $.inArray($.trim($(this).text()), array) > -1
}).find('input').prop('checked', true)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3tjXp/)

Comment: Does not work well .. only selects the first occurrence

Comment: @monda, this is because empty spaces you made -> http://jsfiddle.net/3tjXp/3/ one trim could solve it. Arun's code works fine. :)

Comment: Actually it dynamically sets up data attribute .. so I dont have the control over it.

Comment: So Can U Make Aruns code to work with those spaces ?

Comment: @monda, please check answer above, but Arun will modify his, too, i believe... :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var partyTypes = $("#update-checkbox").attr("data-type"); // gives  "Contractual Customer,Shipper
     $.each(partyTypes.split(','),
         function(i, opt) {

             $( ".checkbox" ).each(function( ) {
                 //console.log(opt);
                 if($( this ).text()==$.trim(opt)) {


                     $(this).find('input:checkbox').prop('checked',true);
                 }
          }) ;

         });
```

Solution for empty spaces... http://jsfiddle.net/jks8S/2/

Answer (score 0):

I'd start by setting the "for" attributes on your labels, and then you only need to make one check.

Or maybe none... No JS = Good.

Then maybe style the label so it's a big clickable area.